# Iterate over multiindex dataframe groups with unequal second index level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex (`Name`, `Date`) DataFrame `df` that I need to process iteratively by `Date` in order to assign a value that is based on both the current and previous Date's Group.

I can't tell how to do this when I have different `Name` sets on different dates.  I've marked the problematic row in the loop below with the comment `HELP!!!`:

```python
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', '20210101', 5.0),  # 1 Jan
                            ('B', '20210101', 3.0),
                            ('C', '20210101', 2.0),
                            ('A', '20210102', 0.0),  # 2 Jan
                            ('C', '20210102', 0.0),
                            ('A', '20210103', 0.0),  # 3 Jan
                            ('C', '20210103', 0.0),
                            ('D', '20210103', 0.0)],
                      columns=('Name', 'Date', 'Dollars')).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])

    # Logic: Each day total wealth sums to $10.
    # Each day: Each person starts with what he had the previous day; 
    #           excess wealth gets allocated evenly to everyone
    
    dft = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('Date'))
    dates = list(dft.groups.keys())
    # Initialize first group:
    previous = dft.get_group(dates[0])

    # Loop over groups in order:
    for date in dates[1:]:
        current = dft.get_group(date)
        current.Dollars = previous.Dollars  # << HELP!!!
        excess = 10.0 - current.Dollars.sum()
        current.Dollars = current.Dollars + excess / current.Dollars.count()
        # Assign the calculated values back to the DataFrame:
        df.loc[current.index] = current
        # Prepare for next iteration:
        previous = current
```

At the `HELP!!!` point I need to somehow accomplish the following:

1. Do a left-join-like assignment of `current.Dollars` to `previous.Dollars`, *disregarding the `Date` index* on `current` and `previous`.  Even if I do a `.reset_index(level=1)` I don't see how I can accomplish this assignment given the fact that the `Name` indexes can vary each day –  Note that in the sample `df` the second day *loses* row Name `B`, and the third day there is a *new* row Name `D`.
2. After disregarding the `Date` level while doing the logic in the loop, I need to somehow recover it to assign the results back to the master `df` on the corresponding `Date`.

---

In this example the value of `df` after the loop finishes should be:

```
               Dollars
Name Date             
A    20210101      5.0
B    20210101      3.0
C    20210101      2.0
A    20210102      6.5
C    20210102      3.5
A    20210103      6.5
C    20210103      3.5
D    20210103      0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in a reduced case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68366165/2662901),
you have to manipulate the indexes in order to do the assignments and then get the values back into the original DataFrame:

```python
# Initialize first group, but take Date out of its index:
previous = dft.get_group(dates[0]).reset_index(level=1)

for date in dates[1:]:
    # Take the Date out of the index:
    current = dft.get_group(date).reset_index(level=1)

    # Get the common keys
    commonKeys = current.index.intersection(previous.index)

    # Do the "left assignment"
    current.loc[commonKeys, 'Dollars'] = previous.loc[commonKeys].Dollars

    # Do your calculations:
    excess = 10.0 - current.Dollars.sum()
    current.Dollars = current.Dollars + excess / current.Dollars.count()

    # Restore the Date column to the index:
    current.set_index('Date', append=True, inplace=True)

    # Assign the calculated values back to the DataFrame:
    df.loc[current.index] = current

    # Prepare for next iteration by removing the Date index again:
    previous = current.reset_index(level=1)
```